# Reactjs global scss file for all variables/mixins etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, directory-structure

I have a project with multiple components that are using scss.

I want to create a single file that stores all my variables and mixins globally that can then be used by any other scss file in my project. How is this possible without having to manually import the file into every scss file that i make?

I've tried making the index.css into a scss file and moved all my variables and mixins there. But nothing really changed. I'm currently using scss modules in my components. Is there perhaps a better way?

my folder structure

```
assets/
    sass/
        _variables.scss
        _mixins.scss

Components/
    .../
        componentName.js
        name.module.scss

index.css
index.js
App.js
```

Comment: Just create a global sass file and import all sass file in it then finally import this file into route component.

Answer (score -1):

All `scss` files you have need to be "connected" via an `@import`, if you want the least work, create a root directory and @import each file once, while making sure that the variables and mixins are imported before the other.

E.g.:

```
// utilities
@import 'utilities/variables', 'utilities/mixins';

//components
@import 'components/buttons', 'components/modals';
```

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work. I have to manually import the variables into every component.